# Same background color on all pages with swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to know if its possible to add the same background color on all my pages?

for exemple i do that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Spacer()
                    //background
                    Color(red:10/255, green: 10/255, blue:25/255)
                    .opacity(0.9)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }
            }
        }
    }




struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                Color(red:10/255, green: 10/255, blue:25/255)
                .opacity(0.9)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Text("Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i am looking to do something to add the background color on the first page and get it on the other pages.

Comment: hay you want to use same background color for the all view right ? and you want global variable which you will use in every view right ?? or something else ?

Comment: yes the same everywhere ( i don't know if it's possible with swift), i'am a web developper and we can add a color for all pages. so i ask if i can event if i to do it

Answer (score 0):

As i Understand correctly you want a global color .Which you will use every in pages background color.

1.So Make your own color variable using Color Extention Like this  :

```
import SwiftUI


extension Color {

     static let myColor = Color(red:4/255, green: 10/255, blue:7/255)
}
```

2. Than use this color like this way :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Spacer()
                //background
                Color.myColor
                .opacity(0.9)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                 Color.myColor
                .opacity(0.9)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Text("Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```